# Kernel of Kähler differential

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $\phi\colon S \to R$ be a homomorphism of rings and denote by $\Omega^1_{R/S}$ the $R$-module of Kähler differentials. Further let $d_{R/S}$ be the canonical exterior derivative.

By definition $\phi(S)\subseteq\text{ker}(d_{R/S})$. Is it known which assumptions on $S,R$ and/or $\phi$ are equivalent to $\phi(S)=\text{ker}(d_{R/S})$?

Comment: For a polynomial ring over a field $k$ of characteristic zero it follows $ker(d)=k$. If $char(k)=p>0$ it follows $d(x^p)=px^{p-1}d(x)=0$ hence $ker(d) \neq k$.

Comment: If $k$ has characteristic $p>0$ the universal derivation $d$ has a large kernel: any element $a^p$ has $d(a^p)=pa^{p-1}d(a)=0$ hence the subring $A^p:=\{a^p: a\in A\} \subseteq A$ is in the kernel.